# AlloyUI "Modal" Component not really modal

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, yui, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I am tryingto use the AlloyUI modal component and while it works pretty well I have the problem, that the underlying UI is still clickable after the modal shows up.

I am using this example : http://alloyui.com/examples/modal/real-world/ and of course I have set modal = true.

The modal is visible (exactly how it should be) but the underlying UI is clickable (menus etc.).

I create the modal (like in the example), I set it to "hide" and I activate it via a button. I am using Liferay 6.2 CE GA4.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved it:

It seemes to be an issue with the z-index property and the underlying theme.
I have set the z-index to 5500 and now the UI is no more clickable.